# How to remotely control a linux from other linux

Tags: linux

I Have two laptops, both having `Manjaro XFCE` installed.

As there are 7 virtual terminals in Linux and we can use them by

1. `Ctrl Alt F1`
2. `Ctrl Alt F2`
3. `Ctrl Alt F3` and so on

Both are connected on same WiFi.

1. Laptop A, as Client
2. Laptop B, as Server

I want my laptop A to remotely control my laptop B, from any of its virtual console.

I don't want just ssh access that's easy.

I Want the complete Linux Desktop in My Virtual console.

Is that possible? If so please guide. I have looked for many sources but people just tell methods of connecting windows to windows.

Their are remote control softwares like anydesk or team-viewer but they Both need an internet connection to work.

so How to overcome this problem. if this thing is possible it would be easy for us to use at least 7 computers in 1 computer.

Thank YOU!

Comment: Are you just looking for [remote desktop clients](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=linux+remote+desktop&ia=web)? What do the virtual consoles have to do with it if you want to access the GUI?

Comment: remote desktop client something like that, i have already stated there are team viewer and anydesk and many more which does the trick, but they need internet to establish the connection. here on same wifi how will that work, In virtual consoles i want because it will show the complete screen there.

Comment: The remote desktop clients mentioned by terdon don't require the internet. Look up VNC.

Comment: I don't think any of the VNC clients you will see if you click on the link I gave you require an internet connection. However, if you don't have an internet connection, please [edit] your question and mention that. You just say the machines are on the same WiFi, you don't say that WiFi has no internet access. But either way, it shouldn't be relevant to VNC clients.

Comment: Machines have internet access, but as y'all know that, if two machines are connected on same WiFi, when we try to ssh into one or the other, or try to copy files one to other, it copies everything, but doesn't use the internet data. if if we use python to create its http server then access the ip address on other machine in same network, and try to download something, it will not also use any of your data.